# Using if-else in build method

Tags: flutter

How can I use if-else construction in build method? 
Now I use double `if`:

```
if (_rapport.isNotEmpty && _rapport.length == 3)
  Container(
    child: Text(_rapport),
  ),
if (_rapport.isEmpty || _rapport.length != 3)
  const Text('wrong input'),
```

while using `else` brings the error:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the **const** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary if-statement.
`condition` ? `true` : `false;`

With context:
`5 > 1` ? `print("this will be printed")` : `print("this won't be printed");`

https://medium.com/run-dart/dart-dartlang-introduction-if-else-conditional-statement-1350a56e2e98?